# How to connect to Sybase using Python Pycharm

Tags: python, sybase, sap-ase

I tried below 2 codes but both didn't worked. Using Pycharm to write Python code. Python version is 3.7 and Sybase ASE.

```
import pyodbc
import urllib
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER=FreeTDS};Server=ee;Database=w;UID=sw2;PWD=Liw9;TDS_Version=8.0;Port=5000;')

#connectionString = ('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT='+port+';SERVER='+server+';PORT='+port+';DATABASE='+db_environment+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password))
db_connection = pyodbc.connect(quoted)
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
cursor.arraysize = 5000
cursor.execute('SELECT top 2 * FROM dbo.rat')
dataset = cursor.fetchall()
if len(dataset) > 0:
    for row in dataset:
        print('D_PK : ', row[0])
        print('D_ID : ', row[1])

cursor.close()
db_connection.close()
```

---

```
import pyodbc
serv = 'Ddsad5'
usr = 'dsda'
passwd = 'dfd9'
db = 'rrg'
prt = '5000'
driver='FreeTDS'

conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=serv, database=db,port = prt,
                  uid=usr, pwd=passwd,TDS_Version=9.5)
print(conn)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT top 2 * FROM dbo.tt1')
row = cursor.fetchall()
print(row)
```

---

Please let me know what code works to connect.

Comment: Formatting corrected

Comment: "Didn't worked". What happened? What didn't happen? Did you get an error? What error?

Comment: quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={FreeTDS};Server=aaa;Database=sss;UID=sh;PWD=Ljs222;TDS_Version=8.0;Port=5000;')
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'